# Convert a dataframe to adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, social-networking, network-analysis

I have a dataset with several overlapping criteria and their frequency of occurrence. I want to plot data as a network(chord) diagram using the  R *circlize* package. I have tried converting the data into an adjacency matrix without success. I could convert the observations which occur in pairs as the matrix. However, I can't do it when there are more than two criteria together. 
 The dataset can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q1kbcznehotrc9/df.csv?dl=0):

The data looks like this

```
 criteria   criteria1   criteria2   criteria3   criteria3   Frequency
 None                   151
 G                  121
 BH                 108
 KBA                    4
 IBA    KBA             172
 AZE    KBA             1
 AZE    IBA KBA         3
 G  KBA             6
 G  IBA KBA         129
 G  AZE KBA         3
 G  AZE KBA IBA     7
 BH KBA             7
 BH IBA KBA         121
 BH AZE KBA         6
 BH AZE IBA KBA     15
 BH G               153
 BH G   KBA         32
 BH G   IBA KBA     200
 BH G   AZE         5
 BH G   AZE KBA     4
 BH G   AZE IBA KBA 44
```

Comment: When there are more than 2 criteria, do you consider every pair combinations an edge?

Comment: Marcelo, Yes! Every pair would be considered as an edge.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get all the pair combinations for the rows where you have more than one criteria and assign the frequency to it. Then you sum the frequencies of the same edges Here is the code:

```
require(dplyr)

#Helper fucntion to get pairwise conbinations of criteria
getEdges <- function(x)
{
        # simplify the list
        v<-unlist(x);

        #Get the pairs and create a dataframe with the frequencies
        cb<-combn(v[1:length(v)-1],2, simplify=F);
        df<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(cb),ncol=2,byrow=T),frequency=as.integer(v[length(v)]),stringsAsFactors=F);

        return (df)
} 

#Get the pairs
edges <- lapply(split(df, seq(nrow(df))), getEdges)

#join the list into one dataframe
edges<-bind_rows(edges)

#Remove empty source and destination
edges <-edges[edges$X1!=""&edges$X2!="",]

#aggregate on edges
aggr <- aggregate(edges$frequency,by=list(edges$X1,edges$X2), FUN=sum)
```

Dataframe `aggr` is the list of edges.

Comment: Marcelo, Thank you! After plotting chord diagram, the numbers look very high and I realize that the pairs can't be considered as an edge. The total number of the observation(sum of frequency) cannot exceed 1292.